# iOS Alert to user with contents of a UITextField when resuming app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to send an alert containing the contents of a UITextField in my `MainViewController` when the app is resumed from multi-tasking. I'm trying to use the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. My main issue is accessing the contents of the `textField` in the `ViewController` from `AppDelegate`.

**AppDelegate :**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil 
    message:CONTENTS OF UITEXTFIELD 
    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad practice to store anything in UI. If your only source of data is some string displayed via label or text view it's a design flaw. You should store this value as text and obtain it via some public interface.

You can store some reference to the `ViewController` in `AppDelegate` or use `NSUserDefaults` saving your data when app goes to background.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the view controller a method `-displayAlert` and call that from your app delegate.

Or, if it's difficult to get a reference to the VC in question, you can have `NSNotificationCenter` post a notification in `-applicationDidBecomeActive`, and register a `-displayAlert` method in the VC to be called when that notification is posted.